imported collection elements update / create / delete when source has no id of target entities
I am looking for efficient collection update stored in database, with the following assumptions:

source has no id of updated / created / deleted records
one and only identification is some kind of index (ex. invoice number and date)
source is an external and independent application (ex. REST API)

I would be grateful if you could point me to some ready-made open source tool, or maybe implemented in JAVA.
